# .Lower() not working in my space themed quiz

Tags: python-3.x, google-forms

I am making a very simple space themed quiz. However, the string method lower() is not working for one of my input statements and I cannot figure out why.

```
gameGreeting = input("Welcome to the space quiz! What is your name? ")
print(f"Nice to meet you, {gameGreeting}!")
gameStart = input(f" Whenever you are ready to begin, please type 'start' : ")

if gameStart.lower() != 'start':
    print("Invalid input. Thanks for trying.")
    quit()

print("Great let's begin!")
score = 0

answerOne = input("Let's start off easy, what planet do we live on? ")
if answerOne.lower() == 'Earth':
    print("Correct! At least you can say you aren't an alien...probably.")
    score += 1
    print("Next question!")
else:
    print("Incorrect. You are being judged heavily right now.")
    print("Next question.")


print("Let's make things a little bit more difficult.")
answerTwo = input("What is the diameter of the Sun? ")

if answerTwo.lower() == "864,000 miles" or answerTwo.lower() == "864000 miles":
    print("Correct! Kudos to you if you didn't google the answer!")
    score += 1
    print("Three more to go! Next question!")
else:
    print("Incorrect. You're 864,000 miles away from winning this quiz.")
    print("Next question.")

answerThree = input("What is the sixth planet away from the Sun? ")
if answerThree.lower() == "Saturn":
    print("Correct! Wow, you're pretty good at this!")
    score += 1
    print("Next question!")
else:
    print("Incorrect. Perhaps you should've paid more attention in science class.")
    print("Next question.")
  
answerFour = input("What are the four gas giants of our solar system in order? ")
if answerFour.lower() == "Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus and Neptune" or answerFour.lower() == "Jupiter Saturn Uranus Neptune":
    print("Correct! You are on a roll!")
    score += 1
    print("Here's the last question!")
else:
    print("Incorrect. Hey we can't all be winners.")
    print("Here's the last question.")

answerFive = input("True or False: The process of an object being compressed vertically and/or horizontally in a powerful gravitational field is called Spagettification." )
if answerFive.lower() == "True":
    print("Correct!! You are truly the master of the Milky Way!")
    score += 1
else:
    print("Incorrect. There's always next time! Try again!")

print("You got " + str(score) + " out of 5 questions correct!")
print("Your total score is " + str((score /5) * 100) + "%! Thank you for playing!")
```

I've reread my code multiple times and I even went on an online code checker, and I still don't understand why it only runs my else statement. What can I try next?

Comment: It's not apparent from your question why you think that `.lower()` is not working.

Comment: Try to simplify problems before posting. Often solutions are found and the question isn't asked at all. For instance, pick one of the failing cases, crack open a python shell, and try just that. Hardcode `answerOne = "Earth"` and then try the test `if answerOne.lower() == 'Earth': print("it worked")`. Now you have something really simple to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you converted the user's input to lowercase.

```
answerOne.lower() == 'Earth':
```

However, you checked against an answer that has uppercase, hence it will never match.
Try changing 'Earth' to 'earth'

```
if answerOne.lower() == 'earth':
```